# Can japanese beautyberry handle wet feet?

Tags: fruits, berries

The plant sale is selling beautyberry this year, and it sounds like a great plant to grow for fruit, so can I grow beautyberry if the water table is only about 1 foot down? It could just be the spring flooding that brought it up high.

Answer (score 1):

If your water table is that high, you need plants used in marginal gardens.

However,

Beauty berries are part of the Laminacae and are quite versatile. 
Here is the article from the RHS for more info. 
[Callicarpa bodinieri 'Profusion'](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/96060/callicarpa-bodinieri-var-giraldii-profusion/details)

Comment: that's the american beautyberry

Comment: you also forgot that if vegetables get constant moisture  they will grow like CRAZY!!!!! see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnmS8gVHlMg

Comment: Not necessarily so! The highest plant death in cultivation is water chlorosis or over watery!! Regardless of where the berry is from, rules remain the same!!